# debug dhcpcd using the lease file at /var/lib/dhcpcd/*.lease

Tags: networking, debug, dhcpcd

I am having problems with the dhcp leases of my eth0 interface. My rpi does not renew its lease when it expires.

My lease file has many special characters, is this normal?

[image]

My configuration :

- Compute Module 4 with Debian bullseye 11 5.18.0

Thank you in advance

Comment: It's a binary file, it isn't meant to be human readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ***only question*** was this: `"My lease file has many special characters, is this normal?"`. The answer to that question is, ***"Yes - it's normal for `dhcpcd`"***. Other DHCP clients - `dhclient` for example - decode the binary data, making it easier to read. AFAICT, the binary data deposited in the lease file by `dhcpcd` is rendered in *human-readable* form using `dhcpcd --dumplease <intfc>` as shown in the example below.

Having answered your question **:)**  I'll [*take a stab at*](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+a+stab+at) helping you resolve what I imagine your problem(s) might be:

- I *suspect* that reviewing your lease file is not going to be x-helpful, but perhaps I am [*selling you short*](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/selling+you+short)? If you feel the path to a solution is in reviewing DHCP lease messages, I'd suggest you take a look at the tool called `dhcpdump`. It's easy to use, and it gives you visibility of both sides of the DHCP client-server exchange: *dhcpcd-to-server*, and *server-to-dhcpcd*.

  I've included an example from running `dhcpdump` on my system at the bottom of this answer. You can install `dhcpdump` from the RPi ports tree in the usual way. The `man dhcpdump` is not hugely helpful, but there are several decent "how-to" guides available; e.g. [1](https://ixnfo.com/en/installing-and-using-dhcpdump.html), [2](https://higaknowit.com/2011/08/04/debugging-dhcpdump/).
- `dhcpcd` has a `debug` mode that you may find useful. You may invoke it from `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` by adding a line with the word `debug`. You may also invoke the debug output from the command line as follows:

  ```bash
  $ sudo dhcpcd --debug wlan0
  sending commands to master dhcpcd process
  send OK 
  $ tail -f /var/log/syslog | grep dhcpcd
    # to view the syslog output (or use journalctl)
  ```
- You didn't provide *anything* re. your `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` file... have you made changes? If so, what are they? Most (> 98%) of the issues with `dhcpcd` are a result of users making changes to this file which [*"backfire"*](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/backfire). So if `dhcpdump` doesn't enable you to find & resolve your issues, you may edit your question to add some of those details & we'll try to help further.

##### dhcpcd --dumplease for `/var/lib/dhcpcd/<intfc>` file:

```bash
$ dhcpcd --dumplease wlan0
broadcast_address='192.168.1.255'
dhcp_lease_time='7200'
dhcp_message_type='5'
dhcp_server_identifier='192.168.1.1'
domain_name='seamus.local'
domain_name_servers='192.168.1.1'
ip_address='192.168.1.143'
network_number='192.168.1.0'
routers='192.168.1.1'
subnet_cidr='24'
subnet_mask='255.255.255.0'
dhcp6_client_id='00010001290fe939b827eb987aaa'
dhcp6_domain_search='seamus.local'
dhcp6_ia_na1_ia_addr1='2605:a601:a80a:b900::133d'
dhcp6_ia_na1_ia_addr1_pltime='4500'
dhcp6_ia_na1_ia_addr1_vltime='7200'
dhcp6_ia_na1_iaid='eb987aaa'
dhcp6_ia_na1_t1='0'
dhcp6_ia_na1_t2='0'
dhcp6_name_servers='2605:a601:a80a:b900:225:90ff:fee0:a775'
dhcp6_reconfigure_accept=''
dhcp6_server_id='0001000123e6bf35002590e0a775'
```

##### dhcpdump usage:

```bash
$ sudo dhcpdump -i wlan0
  TIME: 2022-06-14 21:24:32.585
    IP: 192.168.1.143 (b8:27:eb:68:8c:ca) > 192.168.1.1 (0:25:90:e0:a7:75)
    OP: 1 (BOOTPREQUEST)
 HTYPE: 1 (Ethernet)
  HLEN: 6
  HOPS: 0
   XID: 923bad8b
  SECS: 65535
 FLAGS: 0
CIADDR: 192.168.1.143
YIADDR: 0.0.0.0
SIADDR: 0.0.0.0
GIADDR: 0.0.0.0
CHADDR: b8:27:eb:68:8c:ca:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00
 SNAME: .
 FNAME: .
OPTION:  53 (  1) DHCP message type         3 (DHCPREQUEST)
OPTION:  61 (  7) Client-identifier         01:b8:27:eb:68:8c:ca
OPTION:  57 (  2) Maximum DHCP message size 1472
OPTION:  60 ( 45) Vendor class identifier   dhcpcd-8.1.2:Linux-5.15.32-v7+:armv7l:BCM2835
OPTION:  12 ( 13) Host name                 raspberrypi3b
OPTION: 145 (  1) ???                       01               .
OPTION:  55 ( 14) Parameter Request List      1 (Subnet mask)
                        121 (Classless Static Route)
                         33 (Static route)
                          3 (Routers)
                          6 (DNS server)
                         12 (Host name)
                         15 (Domainname)
                         26 (Interface MTU)
                         28 (Broadcast address)
                         51 (IP address leasetime)
                         54 (Server identifier)
                         58 (T1)
                         59 (T2)
                        119 (Domain Search)

-------------------------------------------------------------------------

  TIME: 2022-06-14 21:24:32.588
    IP: 192.168.1.1 (0:47:90:d3:a7:75) > 192.168.1.143 (b8:27:eb:68:8c:ca)
    OP: 2 (BOOTPREPLY)
 HTYPE: 1 (Ethernet)
  HLEN: 6
  HOPS: 0
   XID: 923bad8b
  SECS: 65535
 FLAGS: 0
CIADDR: 192.168.1.143
YIADDR: 192.168.1.143
SIADDR: 0.0.0.0
GIADDR: 0.0.0.0
CHADDR: b8:27:eb:68:8c:ca:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00
 SNAME: .
 FNAME: .
OPTION:  53 (  1) DHCP message type         5 (DHCPACK)
OPTION:  54 (  4) Server identifier         192.168.1.1
OPTION:  51 (  4) IP address leasetime      5949 (1h39m9s)
OPTION:   1 (  4) Subnet mask               255.255.255.0
OPTION:   3 (  4) Routers                   192.168.1.1
OPTION:   6 (  4) DNS server                192.168.1.1
OPTION:  15 ( 12) Domainname                seamus.local
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```